# Select the Header as the range to search in Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, primary-interop-assembly

I have some text in the header of a Word document.

I have a find and replace method that searches for text and then replaces it if it is found.

How do I only select the header to be the range to search and replace for key words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the header and find inside it?

```
this.Doc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Find()
```

or select the header and search the selection:

```
this.Doc.Sections[1].Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range.Select
Application.Select.Find()
```